# How to compare string to input mips

Tags: string, assembly, dynamic, mips, user-input

I am creating a 3d Tic Tac Toe game in assembly, I am having some issues trying to compare the input string with a stored string from memory. What am I doing wrong and why is what I am doing wrong?

```
buffer: .space 5
pieceXCheck: .asciiz "X"
pieceOCheck: .asciiz "O"


pickAPiece:
li $v0, 4
la $a0, pickAPiecePrompt
syscall

li $v0, 8 #This read input for string
la $a0, buffer
la $a1, 3
syscall

move $a3, $a0

lb $t1, pieceXCheck
beq $a3, $t1, makeAMoveX 

lb $t1, pieceOCheck
beq $a3, $t1, makeAMoveO

li $v0, 4
la $a0, invalidPieceMessage
syscall

jal pickAPiece
```

Comment: You're comparing the address of `buffer` (`$a3`) against a character (`$t1`).

Comment: Okay, so how would i end up fixing this?

Comment: Well, you would probably want to load a byte from somewhere in `buffer`.